Build file sharing server with Raspberry Pi Pico + HDD to load files via ethernet cable
I'm in need of creating a server for hosting PlayStation 2 games. I've heard the Pico is able to achieve 10Mbps of transfer speed, and since I need 8Mbps, 10Mbps is more than enough. So my first question is: Would it be possible to create a file sharing server with the Pico for loading games from it through an ethernet cable?
Don't worry about guessing if the PlayStation 2 can achieve that, it can, my question here is about the server itself.
My second question is: can I connect a HDD to the board and use it for the files?
Please be cool with me, I'm pretty new to this.
Thanks in advance.

I don't know about a "HDD" - that seems quite a stretch for someone who is "pretty new to this" :)  However, you might take a look at the tinyusb repo which has been incorporated in raspberry pi's pico SDK. Perhaps you should install the SDK, and build the examples as a starting point? A little experience might put you in a better position to ask intelligent questions.

A Pico is a microcontroller NOT a computer and lacks the ability to interface to HDD.

So is the ESP32, which could be used to do the same thing that I need to do, but I want to try with pico. I don't want something with an user interface, just something that could be programmed to load files from a hard drive.
